# Histogram of a table with intervals

Tags: r, histogram

I have the following table with scores from 2-9 and their frequencies.
[image: Table]
Now, I need to make a histogram of the full theorethical range (from 0-10).

The histogram has to look like the picture below. So far I have managed to get the correct numbers but i can't seem to get the histogram right.

These are the lines of code I executed:

```
freq = c(1,3,2,3,5,6,3,2)
score = 2:9
raw = rep(score,freq)
sq = seq(0,10,2)
t = table(cut(raw,breaks=sq))
```

t holds the following result, which corresponds with the values in the histogram I want.

[image: Values]

[image: Desired result]

Comment: you would have better luck with `barplot`

Comment: try something like `hist(raw,breaks = seq(0, 10, 2))`